# Matt Kruse's Javascript sorter - reverse default sort order

Tags: javascript, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Matt Kruse's Javascript-based client-side table sorter. It's unbelievably simple to use and set up, and tremendously useful. HOWEVER, while I can set up the table to sort by the second column by default using `"class='table-autosort:1"`, I seem to be unable to get it to sort in descending order by default.

I'm hoping it's doable, just undocumented. If not, does anyone have a clever solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bug (or two in [table.js](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/libsource.php/table/source/table.js)).

If you replace line 909:

```
tdata.sorttype=Sort['"+type+"'];
```

with:

```
tdata.sorttype=Sort[type];
```

and then add this line:

```
args.sorttype = tdata.sorttype;
```

before line 915 (which is currently):

```
table.sort(t,args);
```

Then I believe default sorting should work properly.

Now, you need a method which does the descending sort like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sort['default_descending'] = function(a, b) {
        return (a==b)?0:(a>b)?-1:1;
  }
</script>
```

Make sure to inlude this **after** the included `table.js` file.

Now, you need to give the column in your table the appropriate class (something like):

```
<th class="table-sortable:default_descending">Text</th>
```

If you use this class for the autosort column, it should auto-sort descending now.

[*I emailed the author to let him know about the bug*]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
To be able to sort descending, just change mysql query as `order by field_name desc;`
This alone wont solve your problem, you need to remove number from sorting class `"class='table-autosort:1"` to `"class='table-autosort"`